# Does pandas.tz_localize allow me to specify a timezone without DST?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python-2.7 and pandas 0.16.1, and was hoping to use the ambiguous key with an ndarray to specify that none of my TimeSeries is DST -- it is all Standard time. I see that the documentation says "(note that this flag is only applicable for ambiguous times)" and so it looks like it doesn't work as a blanket adjustment, only for the 1am/2am issues.

Is there a timezone I can specify other than 'US/Eastern' that indicates it should remain standard? 'UTC-5'? 'EST' doesn't work, it also converts to UTC-4 at 3am on the appropriate day in March.

Does bug [#8917](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8917) mean that I am out of luck until 0.17 is released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Etc/GMT+5'` should also work.

http://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timetimezones.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I use now. It's important to note that the 'Etc/GMT+X' is consistent across the US, at least. However, 'EST' is a valid label for Standard Time, but 'PST' is not, at least on my system.

Answer (score 1):

From the solar model (pvlib-python) issues help:

`tz_localize(pytz.FixedOffset(-5*60))` 
instead of 
`tz_localize('US/Eastern')` gives me the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use UTC time zone.

```
from pytz import UTC
```

Comment: To clarify, I have data with a timestamp already that I am trying to convert to UTC, but the conversion function does not seem capable of converting to UTC without assuming the time periods between March and November will be UTC-4, when in fact, all of the timestamps are UTC-5.

Comment: The timestamp comes from a solar model.